# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\log(\log n)^s}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does this series converge?
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\log(\log n)^s}$$
I wrote it as
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{ns\log(\log n)}$$
and I dont know how to deal with the double logarithm. This has to be shown with Cauchy's condensation test.

Comment: Multiply the whole series with $2^n$, and everywhere you see $n$, change that to a $2^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Cauchy's Condensation Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) , assuming $\;s>0\;$ (otherwise divergence is almost trivial) :

$$\frac{2^n}{2^n\log(\log 2^n)^s}=\frac1{s\log(n\log2)}=\frac1{s\log n+s\log\log2}$$

and since the last term's series clearly diverges also ours does diverge.

Comment: shouldnt it be convergent, as $\frac{1}{term}$ tends to $0$ ?

Comment: Not at all, @sj134: $$\frac1{s\log n+s\log\log2}\ge\frac1{2s\log n}\ge\frac1{2sn}$$ and by the comparison test the series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: firstly, I am pretty sure that $s$ is supposed to be the exponential of the outer logarithm, secondly, use the integral test.

Comment: We did not cover the integral test yet, so I cannot use it.